# Nested folder structure for views in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can i alter my views folder structure in MVC? I wanna use nested folder structure.

Views (Folder)
    - Content (Folder) 
        - Admin (Folder)
           - Index.aspx

Controller
    - AdminController.cs

AdminController -> has an action Index which returns the view Index from Views->Content->Admin-Index.aspx

Is this possible and how can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may take a look at [areas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793.aspx) or write a custom view engine. Scott Hanselmann [blogged about a mobile view engine](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABetterASPNETMVCMobileDeviceCapabilitiesViewEngine.aspx) but you could adapt it to your needs and folder structure.

Comment: i saw that, but its different from what i am expecting. Let me try to do something like that.. by the way.. do u have any link with some other sample same like my requirement. Let me try Scott's blog-second link

Comment: @Nimesh, check this one also: http://coderjournal.com/2009/05/creating-your-first-mvc-viewengine/ You just have to specify the `ViewLocationFormats` variable.

Comment: I saw one link where instead of crating custom view engine, just give the physical path.Is there any implication for this???? http://forums.asp.net/p/1508860/3588122.aspx#3588122

Comment: @Nimesh, yes that's also an option but if you later decide to change your folder structure it would be much easier to change it only at one place instead of modifying all your controller actions.

Comment: really confused. So u mean to say by specifying full path, its easier than creating custom view engine? :)

Comment: @Nimesh, no, I mean it's worse. You need to hardcode full paths inside your controller actions. I would recommend you creating a custom view engine for this purpose.

Comment: thanks a lot.. i am trying to create a custom view engine. now.